# Requirejs multiple modules from one file

Tags: javascript, module, requirejs

I need to use 2 modules from one file.

**index.html**:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <script data-main="app/main" src="app/require.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>

        </body>
    </html>
```

**main.js**:

```js
 require(['modules/message', 'modules/another-module'], function(message, anotherModule) {
        alert(anotherModule);
    });
```

**modules/message.js**:

```js
define(function() {
    return 'Hello there!';
});

define('another-module', function() {
    return 'hi there!';
});
```

For some reason Chrome goes with error **Uncaught Error: Script error for: modules/another-module**

Directory structure:

```
|- appDirectory
|-- app
|--- modules
|---- message.js
|--- main.js
|--- require.js
|-- index.html
```

So the question is: how can I load 2 modules from one file using just one require expression? Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is that when you name a module with `define` you have to give it the **full name** that you intend do use for the module. So it should be `define('modules/another-module'`

But this is not the only problem. You require it like this:

```
require(['modules/message', 'modules/another-module'],
```

There are multiple ways in which this can go down but there are two principal ways that are of interest here:

1. RequireJS completely loads `modules/message` *before* it starts trying to load `modules/another-module`. By the time it gets to the second module, it already has a `define` for it. Everything is fine.
2. RequireJS starts loading `modules/another-module` *first*. So it will fetch a file named `modules/another-module.js` and won't find it, which will cause an error.

Note that a `require` call by itself imposes no order on the dependencies passed to it. So RequireJS is completely free to start loading modules in whatever order it wants. You can solve this second problem by using [`bundles`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-bundles) in your runtime configuration. For instance:

```
bundles: {
    "modules/message": [ "modules/another-module" ]
}
```

Comment: So here, one important point i understood, there is no order on loading dependencies.

Comment: The list of modules passed to `require` does not define an order. It is through `define` calls that order is created. If you call `require(['a', 'b'])` and `a` lists `b` in its dependencies passed to `define`, then `b` will necessarily load before `a`.